# Insert calligraphy TeX in FrameLabel

Tags: plotting, legending, latex

I want to put some Tex code in my FrameLabels so they are consistent with my equations. So far, I managed to do it using things like:

```
ToExpression["\\Delta\\nu_{m} (MHz)", TeXForm]
```

Now I want to display calligraphy letters like this: $\mathcal{F}_{t}$. If I just write:

```
ToExpression["\\mathcal{F}_{t}", TeXForm]
```

I get a simple $F_{t}$. How can I do that?

Comment: How about `\[ScriptCapitalF]`?

Comment: That would generate a different cursive font. I could use that and change my TeX code to match that output...

Comment: Have you already tried [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX)?

Comment: Heard about it, but I don't think it would work on Mathematica online.

Answer (score 4):

Give [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX) a try.

```
<< MateX`

Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"\\text{$\\Delta\\nu_{m}$ (MHz)}", "\\mathcal{F}_{t}"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I heard about it, but I can't use it on Mathematica online.